# d3.js javascript crazy clientHeight property

Tags: javascript, d3.js, properties, window

I'm getting a crazy, constant clientHeight value (= 154) whenever I run the following code; however, my clientWidth property is responsive to changing window size every time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Plot Viewer</title>
    <script src="js/lib/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style> 

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2px;

      /* Make the chart container fill the page using CSS. */
      #chart {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>

      var chartDiv = document.getElementById("chart");
      var svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg");

      function render() {

        // Extract the width and height that was computed by CSS.
        var width = chartDiv.clientWidth;
        var height = chartDiv.clientHeight;

        svg
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d %H:%M");

        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        // define the line
        var line = d3.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.solar); });

        // Get the data
        d3.csv("data_fred.csv", function(error, data) {
          if (error) throw error;

          // format the data
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.time = parseTime(d.time);
            d.solar = +d.solar;
          });

         // Scale the range of the data
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.solar; })]);

          // Add the line path.
          svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);

          // Add the X Axis
          svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d %H:%M  ")))
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

          // Add the Y Axis
          svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        });
      }

      d3.selectAll("g > *").remove()
      render();

      // Redraw based on the new size whenever the browser window is resized.
      window.addEventListener("resize", render);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get a fine, although squashed (154 px tall) plot. Any ideas as to why the clientHeight property remains constant, despite window resizes?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't add comments so I'll post it is as an answer and hope it helps you someway.

Could you clarify what behavior did you expect? Live real code example (codepen?) could be useful too.

In example you posted you didn't close the .line style (missing **}** curly bracket) but it's hard to tell whether you deleted it accidentally while clearing your code to post question or is it somehow related.

---

The helping part:
You didn't change display, nor width property of #chart style so it's probably dependent of browser width (div usually take 100% width), however it's height is dependent only of it's content. If you fill #chart with constant height content then the clientHeight is constant as well.

Comment: ...added the rest of the code sample. I expected the clientHeight to be some useful % of the window height (starting around 500), not a constant 154 px, and change with a window resize, like the width does. The width is eturned reliably. The chart elements are not removed with the remove() either, but that's another issue.

Comment: The .line style } closure did it. Thanks!

Comment: happy to help, you should probably close the question then :)
If you would like height to response to window size just set in in styles to for example 50% (or some other relative value)